# Drupal 7: Custom modules in nodes

Tags: drupal-nodes

I am using Drupal 7 for my project. I have custom blocks created. These blocks contain news items from an RSS feed. Each news item is identifiable uniquely from the database.

For each news item displayed individually in custom block, I need to have ratings and comments added. I believe comments and ratings can be easily handled on nodes. Hence, I am looking to convert custom blocks into nodes.

Q1: Is this the right approach?, If not, any suggestions on how best to approach this?

Q2: Any suggestions on which modules / extensions that can help me achieve this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Creating nodes seems to be the right approach to me. basically I would think of three modules if I had this task

## [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)

It allows you to consume an RSS feed (among other things) then create a node per feed item.

You will create the content type yourself and have full control on the rating/comments using normal drupal modules and functionality.

## [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

It allows you to show your content in many ways and even control access to them.

## [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron), [Poormanscron](https://www.drupal.org/project/poormanscron)

Both of them are optional, you might not need any of them.

As a part of your feeds module installation, you will need to enable/run the cron job in your site to consume the RSS feed every defined time.

- Elysia Cron allows your run different cron jobs for different modules in a different time span for each.
- Poormanscron enables you to run cron jobs if you are on shared hosting with no access to the system cron tab.